# Como acceder correctamente a la base de datos en Firebase?

Tags: java, firebase

**Hola, mundo!**

Mi problema es que cuando trato de ingresar a mi base de datos que se encuentra en Firebase me lanza un error, el cual desconozco su paradero). Lo que quiero conseguir es que mi app java que posee el papel de administrar la base de datos pueda ingresar a ella y escribir información en una de sus bases hijas.

**Información de consola**

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
feb 26, 2019 9:17:52 AM boxadministrator.BoxAdministrator$1 run
GRAVE: null
java.io.IOException: Error reading credentials from stream, 'type' field not specified.
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.fromStream(GoogleCredentials.java:168)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.fromStream(GoogleCredentials.java:141)
    at boxadministrator.FirebaseConexion.algo(FirebaseConexion.java:42)
    at boxadministrator.BoxAdministrator$1.run(BoxAdministrator.java:58)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

El .json (el que posee las claves  y otros datos) pertenece a una aplicación aplicación Android ya que la aplicación Java sera un simple portal de administración para los datos que encuentran en la base de datos, para que luego la app móvil los obtenga. **Uso un .json de un proyecto android porque el proyecto de Firebase esta orientado a este desconosco si debe descargar un .json para java especial.**

**Mi base de datos prueba**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**El código de iniciación de los servicios de Firebase**

```
        FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\ABRAHAM-JOSE\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\BoxAdministrator\\google-services.json"));

    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
        .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
        .setDatabaseUrl("https://<Base>.firebaseio.com/")
        .build();

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

    // As an admin, the app has access to read and write all data, regardless of Security Rules
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        .getReference("restricted_access/secret_document");
    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          Object document = dataSnapshot.getValue();

          System.out.println(document);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        }
    });
```

Una de las cosas que pensé fue de que tal vez no encontraba el archivo .json, porque tal vez no existía en esa ruta, pero si existe.

**Mi código de escritura**

```
     public void Escribir() {
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("base_junior");
    System.out.println(ref);
    DatabaseReference usersRef = ref.child("name");
    System.out.println(usersRef);
    Map<String, String> users = new HashMap<>();
    users.put("alanisawesome", "Julio");
    users.put("gracehop", "jull");
    System.out.println(users);

    usersRef.setValueAsync(users);

}
```

**Gracias y espero su pronto apoyo.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema esta en el `google-services.json` que estas usando, lo que deberias hacer es crear una nueva clave.

El error

> java.io.IOException

Es debido a esta linea

```
FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\ABRAHAM-JOSE\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\BoxAdministrator\\google-services.json"));
```

Para generar una clave nueva puedes hacerlo desde la consola

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asegurate que el path `new File("C:\\Users\\ABRAHAM-JOSE\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\BoxAdministrator\\google-services.json"));` es el correcto

Comment: Ok amigo ya descargue y ubique en el codigo el archivo json correcto pero me da este error al iniciar SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

Comment: Ok amigo su respuesta me fue util, el problema era que me faltaba la libreria SLF4J.